# Метод read класса Reader

Tags: java, io, inputstream

Занимаюсь на одном не без известном сайте. Тема потоков ввода и вывода.
Объясняется класс Reader и его методы. Не понимаю одной вещи:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что значит первые два байта всегда нули?
read() Читает чары. Расширяя их до инта. Я попробовал прочитать первый символ через локальный документ на компьютере:

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Reader reader = new FileReader("/uploads/1.txt"); // документ из 1 символа - англ. буква a
    char a = (char) reader.read();
    System.out.println(a); //выводит а
}
}
```

Никаких нулей не выводит. Может ошибка в тексте?

Comment: в примере, котрый Вы привели в вопросе - по моему, никакого "расширения до int" не происходит. Поэтому у Вас читается "байт в байт". я не знаю, кто это писал, но, возможно, он имел в виду, что "если не преобразовывать к (char) - то будут читаться Int'ы с нулевыми старшими байтами". Но тогда уж не два, а три байта с нулями :-) А вообще - ошибка в тексте, конечно :-)

Comment: метод read() класса Reader возвращает инт. В примере, конечно, я читаю этот символ и делаю down-кастинг до чара.

Comment: А почему три байта с нулями? Если чар - 2 байта. Инт - 4 байта. 4 - 2 = 2.

Comment: Очень верное замечание! насчет char - забыл, какой он в Java

Comment: Имеются ввиду 2 старших байта в int-е. Чтоб это увидеть сделайте `System.out.println(String.format("0x%08x", (int)a));` Ну а детали про это в https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html. Ну и конечно стоит прочитать доку https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read--

Comment: Всем спасибо. Всё стало понятно. Автор статьи видимо это и имел ввиду, но ввёл в заблуждение.